# Is $\text{Hom}(A\oplus B, G) = \text{Hom}(A, G)\oplus \text{Hom}(B, G)$ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I'm reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, and in the proof of the Universal Coefficients Theorem (Page 192), it says for abelian groups $A$ and $B$, and an arbitrary group $G$, we have $\text{Hom}(A\oplus B, G) = \text{Hom}( A, G)\oplus \text{Hom}( B, G)$.

Is that true?

Take $A = B = \mathbb{N}$ and the $G$ the free product $\mathbb{N} * \mathbb{N}$. What is the corresponding map between $\text{Hom}( A\oplus B, G)$ and $\text{Hom}( A, G)\oplus \text{Hom}(B, G)$?

Thanks.

Comment: I've cleaned up the post. Note that to make your TeX compile, you need to put dollar signs around it.

Comment: The statement in Hatcher's book is wrong (as are the two other answers so far). Are you sure that $G$ is not assumed to be abelian?

Comment: I'm not sure whether Hatcher means that $G$ is abelian. He does not state that $G$ is abelian in the proof of the universal coefficients theorem after all. However he assumes it is abelian in the rest of the section ( Section 3.1 ). Maybe $G$ is assumed to be abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A,B$ are groups, then $A \times B$ is the product in the category of groups, meaning that $\hom(-,A \times B) \cong \hom(-,A) \times \hom(-,B)$. But we also have a description of the covariant hom functor $\hom(A \times B,-)$. Namely:

$$\hom(A \times B,G) \cong \{f \in \hom(A,G),g \in \hom(B,G) : \forall a \in A, b \in B(f(a) \text{ commutes with } g(b))\}$$
It is easy to write down maps in both directions and to show that they are inverse to each other. One uses that $(a,b)=(1,b)(a,1)=(a,1)(1,b)$ in $A \times B$.

If $G$ is abelian, then the commutation condition becomes superfluous, so that $\hom(A \times B,G) \cong \hom(A,G) \times \hom(B,G)$.

If $G$ is not abelian, this is not (always) the case, even if $A,B$ are abelian. In fact, $\hom(A,-) \times \hom(B,-) \cong \hom(A * B,-)$, where $A * B$ is the coproduct of $A,B$ in the category of groups (unfortunately known as "free product"), and the natural map $A * B \to A \times B$ is surjective but no isomorphism when $A,B$ are non-trivial: If $a \in A, b \in B$ are $\neq 1$, then $aba^{-1} b^{-1}$ lies in the kernel. Actually the kernel is generated, as a normal subgroup, by these elements - this follows from the isomorphism above and the Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: Hatcher says, in page 186 "For a fixed abelian group G...". So he's correct.

Comment: @Pedro: This is not a comment on my answer, but rather on the question by user150248. Or even an answer.

Comment: You wrote "The statement in Hatcher's book is wrong (as are the two other answers so far). Are you sure that G is not assumed to be abelian?".

Comment: I didn't write this in my answer ....

Comment: Sure. Hey, I was just trying to clear things up! ;) Your answer is very informative and useful, as always.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true (if we interpret the $=$ to mean natural isomorphism).

To describe the map $\text{Hom}(A,G)\oplus\text{Hom}(B,G)\to \text{Hom}(A\oplus B,G)$, suppose we have $f\in\text{Hom}(A,G)$ and $g\in\text{Hom}(B,G)$. Define a map $h\in\text{Hom}(A\oplus B,G)$ by $h(a,b) = f(a) + g(b)$. I'll leave it to you to check that the map $(f,g)\mapsto h$ is an isomorphism.

Also, note that $\mathbb{N}$ is not an abelian group, it's only a commutative monoid. Maybe you meant to use $\mathbb{Z}$ in your example? But also $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is not an abelian group. The free product of two groups is never abelian (unless one of the groups is trivial).

Comment: The OP writes "an arbitrary group $G$".

Comment: Hah! I overlooked that, because $G$ should so obviously be required to be abelian.